# Cortex hasMany not creating entries in m2m table

Tags: php, orm, has-many, fat-free-framework

Hi I coudln't get Cortex hasMany to hasMany relation working so I made a simple test. I created two classes, CortexTestA and CortexTestB in my models namespace

```
namespace models;

use DB\Cortex;

class CortexTestA extends Cortex {

    protected $fieldConf = array(
        'name' => array(
        'type' => 'VARCHAR256',
        'nullable' => false
        ),
        'cortextestb' => array(
        'has-many' => array('models\CortexTestB', 'cortextesta', 'cortextest_a_b')
        )
    );
    // constructor etc. follows
```

This is the field conf for CortexTestB:

```
    'cortextesta' => array(
        'has-many' => array('models\CortexTestA', 'cortextestb', 'cortextest_a_b')
    )
```

Next I ran the setup command

```
\Models\CortexTestA::setup();
\Models\CortexTestB::setup();
```

But already something strange happens, both tables now have obsolete fields:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cortextesta` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cortextestb` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cortextestb` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cortextesta` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
 )
```

The m2m table does get created correctly though:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cortextest_a_b` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cortextesta` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cortextestb` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

But now when I run this

```
$cta = new \models\CortexTestA();
$cta->name = "SomethingA";
$cta->save();

// Results in: INSERT INTO `cortextesta` (`id`, `name`, `cortextestb`) VALUES
//        (1, 'SomthingA', NULL);
```

and then this:

```
$cta = new \models\CortexTestA();
$cta->load(array('id = ?', 1));

$ctb = new \models\CortexTestB();
$ctb->name = "SomethingB";
$ctb->cortextesta[] = $cta;
$ctb->save();
```

the relationship table cortextest_a_b remains empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update: I just ran the cortex unit tests and the same seems to be happening.
Table news has a tags2 field and table tags has a news field.
The unit test results indicate success, yet table news_tags remains empty.
Maybe I'm not doing anything wrong, could something be misconfigured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the relation is still empty, the property getter currently returns `NULL`. That's why the array modification unfortunately doesn't work. You can easily workaround that like this:

```
if (!$ctb->cortextesta)
  $ctb->cortextesta = array($cta);
else
  $ctb->cortextesta[] = $cta;
$ctb->save();
```

I'll see if I can optimized this a bit. The issue about the obsolete fields is indeed a bug. I'll patch that soon. thanks.